# Reading in a JSON response with a dojo deferred callback method

Tags: javascript, json, dojo

So I have scoured the web looking for a solution to this, and I cannot seem to find an answer, as everyone is using getElementById and I do not believe that to be a correct solution to my problem. I am trying to use this Javascript function:

```
Services.stuff = function() {

function initializer() {
    var deferred = dummyService.getStuff();
    deferred.addCallbacks(callback, errback);
}

function calculateSomething(amount) {
    return Math.round(amount / this.param* 100) / 100;
}

function newThingy(code, param, description) {
      return {
        code: code,
        numbers: param,
        description: description,
         calculateMinutes: calculateMinutes
     }
}

var callback = function(response) {
    for (object in response) {
        //do something.
    }
};

var errback = function(error) {
    //do something.
}
```

}();

To read a JSON response. The response is an object that contains other java objects and looks like this:

```
    {
   "id":1,
   "result":{
      "map":{
         "018004":{
            "param":10,
            "description":"Description",
            "javaClass":"Java Class",
            "code":"018004"
         },
         "018006":{
            "param":11,
            "description":"Description",
            "javaClass":"Java Class",
            "code":"018006"
         },
         "018005":{
            "param":12,
            "description":"Description",
            "javaClass":"Java Class",
            "code":"018005"
         },
      },
      "javaClass":"com.google.common.collect.RegularImmutableMap"
     }
    }
```

Basically I need to read that response with my javascript and then have the javascript return a java object. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: What is getStuff? im guessing its returning a promise?

Comment: getStuff is the service method called, which returns the objects. Sorry I had to changed variable and method names to preserve privacy :/.